# Hausman Test for Logistic Panel Regression Models

Tags: r, panel, logistic-regression, panel-data

I want to do the `Hausman` test to determine whether `random effects` specification would be appropriate for my panel data. When I tried to use `ph-test` for a `Logistic Regression` model, I got the message

```
Error in UseMethod("phtest"Ω :no applicable method for 'phtest' 
applied to an object of class "c('maxLik', 'maxim', 'list')"".
```

Is there a package in R that I can use to run `Hausman` test for `logistic regression`?